# Is there a shorter way to say "b raised to the n-th power"

Tags: exponentiation

$b^n$

Alternatives that I know are correct:

- "b raised to the power of n"
- "the n-th power of b"

Can I just say

- "b raised to n" or
- "b to n"

or are these technically wrong?

Comment: I've heard many times "b to the n-th". Any of the above expressions seem fine to me. I would understand what you want to say.

Comment: I think, @Andrei, that OP’s last offer sounds unidiomatic.

Answer (score 3):

I always heard it read as "b to the n"

Comment: And, having sat in high-school classes since about 2001, I am still amazed to hear the students and teachers read it as “$b$ to the power of $n$”. I think that I myself usually say “$b$ to the $n$-th”.